# OneToMany bidirectional relation not showing childs

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

When i'm creating templateDir with parentId it's showing correctly after getAllTree method, and if i'm creating templateFile without parentId it's also showing correctly.
**But when i'm creating templateFile with parentDirId it's not showing at all**. It lies in db but not correctly recognized as a child for parentDir i assume.

I have 2 entity classes: TemplateFile and TemplateDirectory:

- TemplateFile

  ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "template_files")
   public class TemplateFile implements TemplateEntity{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private long id;

   @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
   private String name;

   @Column(name = "local_path")
   private String localPath;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "directory_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
   private TemplateDirectory parentDir;

   @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
   private Instant createdAt;
  ```
- TemplateDirectory

  ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "template_directories")
   public class TemplateDirectory implements TemplateEntity{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private long id;

   @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
   private String name;

   @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
   private Instant createdAt;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
   private TemplateDirectory parent;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   private Set<TemplateDirectory> childDirs;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentDir", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   private Set<TemplateFile> childFiles;
  ```

  When i am creating new TemplateFile with parentDirectory i use following method to ensure bidirectional relation(same for creating new directory):

  ```
  public void addChildTemplate(TemplateFile template) {
   template.setParentDir(this);
   this.childFiles.add(template);
  }
  ```
- CreateTemplateMethod:

  ```
  @Transactional
  public TemplateTreeDTO createTemplate(TemplateDTO templateDTO) throws 
  NotFoundException {
  TemplateEntity templateEntity;
  if (templateDTO instanceof TemplateFileDTO) {
      TemplateFileDTO templateFileDTO = (TemplateFileDTO) templateDTO;
      if (templateFileDTO.getParentId() == null) {
          templateEntity = templateMapper.createEntityFromTemplateDTO(templateFileDTO, null);
      } else {
          TemplateDirectory parentDirectory = findTemplateDirectoryById(templateFileDTO.getParentId());
          templateEntity = templateMapper.createEntityFromTemplateDTO(templateFileDTO, parentDirectory);
      }
      templateFileRepository.saveAndFlush((TemplateFile) templateEntity);
  } else {
      TemplateDirectoryDTO templateDirectoryDTO = (TemplateDirectoryDTO) templateDTO;
      if (templateDirectoryDTO.getParentId() == null) {
          templateEntity = templateMapper.createEntityFromTemplateDTO(templateDirectoryDTO, null);
      } else {
          TemplateDirectory parentDirectory = findTemplateDirectoryById(templateDirectoryDTO.getParentId());
          templateEntity = templateMapper.createEntityFromTemplateDTO(templateDirectoryDTO, parentDirectory);
      }
      templateDirectoryRepository.saveAndFlush((TemplateDirectory) templateEntity);
  }
  return getAllTree();
  ```

  }
- TemplateMapper methods:

  ```
   public TemplateEntity createEntityFromTemplateDTO(TemplateDTO templateDTO, TemplateDirectory parentDirectory) {
   if (templateDTO instanceof TemplateFileDTO) {
       TemplateFile templateFile = new TemplateFile();
       updateEntityFromTemplateDTO(templateFile, templateDTO, parentDirectory);
       return templateFile;
   } else {
       TemplateDirectory templateDirectory = new TemplateDirectory();
       updateEntityFromTemplateDTO(templateDirectory, templateDTO, parentDirectory);
       return templateDirectory;
    }
   }

   public TemplateEntity updateEntityFromTemplateDTO(TemplateEntity templateEntity, TemplateDTO templateDTO,
                                               TemplateDirectory parentDirectory) {
   if (templateEntity instanceof TemplateFile) {
       TemplateFile templateFile = (TemplateFile) templateEntity;
       TemplateFileDTO templateFileDTO = (TemplateFileDTO) templateDTO;
       templateFile.setName(templateFileDTO.getName());
       templateFile.setLocalPath(templateFileDTO.getFilePath());
       templateFile.setCreatedAt(Instant.now());
       if (parentDirectory != null) {
           parentDirectory.addChildTemplate(templateFile);
       } else
           templateFile.setParentDir(null);
       return templateFile;
   } else {
       TemplateDirectory templateDirectory = (TemplateDirectory) templateEntity;
       TemplateDirectoryDTO templateDirectoryDTO = (TemplateDirectoryDTO) templateDTO;
       templateDirectory.setName(templateDirectoryDTO.getName());
       templateDirectory.setCreatedAt(Instant.now());
       templateDirectory.setParent(parentDirectory);
       Set<TemplateDirectoryDTO> childDirectories = templateDirectoryDTO.getDirectories();
       if (childDirectories != null && !childDirectories.isEmpty()) {
           templateDirectory
                   .setChildDirs(childDirectories
                                         .stream()
                                         .map(templateDirectoryDTO1 -> createEntityFromTemplateDTO(templateDirectoryDTO1,
                                                                                                   templateDirectory))
                                         .map(template -> (TemplateDirectory) template)
                                         .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet()));
       }
       Set<TemplateFileDTO> childTemplates = templateDirectoryDTO.getTemplates();
       if (childTemplates != null && !childTemplates.isEmpty()) {
           templateDirectory
                   .setChildFiles(childTemplates
                                          .stream()
                                          .map(templateDTO1 -> createEntityFromTemplateDTO(templateDTO1, templateDirectory))
                                          .map(template -> (TemplateFile) template)
                                          .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet()));
       }
       return templateDirectory;
    }
   }
  ```

I'm trying to show all "TemplateTree" by using repository methods findAllByParentIsNull for templateFiles and templateDirectories:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public TemplateTreeDTO getAllTree() {
    Set<TemplateFileDTO> rootTemplates =
            templateFileRepository.findAllByParentDirIsNull()
                                  .stream()
                                  .map(templateMapper::createTemplateDTOFromEntity)
                                  .map(templateDTO -> (TemplateFileDTO) templateDTO)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());

    Set<TemplateDirectoryDTO> rootTemplateDirectories =
            templateDirectoryRepository.findAllByParentIsNull()
                                       .stream()
                                       .map(templateMapper::createTemplateDTOFromEntity)
                                       .map(templateDTO -> (TemplateDirectoryDTO) templateDTO)
                                       .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());
    TemplateTreeDTO templateTreeDTO = new TemplateTreeDTO();
    templateTreeDTO.setTemplates(rootTemplates);
    templateTreeDTO.setDirectories(rootTemplateDirectories);

    return templateTreeDTO;
}
```

Comment: There's no code showing how a `TemplateFile` would be created, so how could we find out what's missing?

Comment: Is the database correct after saving? What's the code of `templateMapper.createEntityFromTemplateDTO`?

Comment: I'm sorry about that. Edited my answer with createTemplate method and mapper methods

Comment: @Smutje the database seems correct because template_files table has an entity of templateFile with correct parentDirectory_id

Comment: Where's the code for `parentDirectory.addChildTemplate(templateFile);` and `getAllTree()`?

Comment: If your database state is correct I assume it has something to do with reading that state from the database and not with creating the table entries.

Comment: @Smutje i added getAllTree method along with addChildTemplate to my question.

Comment: Your `getAllTree` only finds the root templates and root template directories. Where should the template that is not a root template but a template in a specific directory be included? Have the root template directories a list of files? I doubt that because you call `templateMapper::createTemplateDTOFromEntity` for both types.

Comment: @Smutje i can only tell that the database state seems correct because persisted TemplateFile has corrent parentDirId. But nothing to say about if it exists in parentDir Set<TemplateFile> childTemplates. After debugging before saveAndFlush on CreateTemplate method both TemplateFile and parent TemplateDir have correct relation(templateFile exists in parentDir childSet and has correct ParentDirId). I think something can go wrong after saveAndFlush method.

Comment: If the database is correct everything relying on the database should be correct as soon as you restart your application and assuming you don't have any third party caching active, because your application then reads everything fresh from the database.

Comment: @Smutje, Thank you a lot for your help!!! I found out that i literally don't set List of Templates in TemplateDirectoryDTO...so simple and obvious. You helped me with your suggestion to check not persisting but reading the state from the database.

Answer (score 0):

The fault was my carelessness...  With the help of

> @Smutje

I found out that i literally don't set List of Templates in TemplateDirectoryDTO...so simple and obvious. Hope somebody find out this question useful as an example of OneToMany bidirectional relation.

After updating TemplateMapper.createTemplateDTOFromEntity to :

```
public TemplateDTO createTemplateDTOFromEntity(TemplateEntity templateEntity) {
    if (templateEntity instanceof TemplateFile) {
        TemplateFile templateFile = (TemplateFile) templateEntity;
        TemplateFileDTO templateFileDTO = new TemplateFileDTO();
        templateFileDTO.setId(templateFile.getId());
        templateFileDTO.setName(templateFile.getName());
        templateFileDTO.setFilePath(templateFile.getLocalPath());
        TemplateDirectory parentDirectory = templateFile.getParentDir();
        templateFileDTO.setParentId(parentDirectory == null ? null : parentDirectory.getId());
        return templateFileDTO;
    } else {
        TemplateDirectory templateDirectory = (TemplateDirectory) templateEntity;
        TemplateDirectoryDTO templateDirectoryDTO = new TemplateDirectoryDTO();
        templateDirectoryDTO.setId(templateDirectory.getId());
        templateDirectoryDTO.setName(templateDirectory.getName());
        TemplateDirectory parentDirectory = templateDirectory.getParent();
        templateDirectoryDTO.setParentId(parentDirectory == null ? null : parentDirectory.getId());
        Set<TemplateDirectory> childDirectories = templateDirectory.getChildDirs();
        if (childDirectories != null && !childDirectories.isEmpty()) {
            templateDirectoryDTO.setDirectories(childDirectories
                                                        .stream()
                                                        .map(this::createTemplateDTOFromEntity)
                                                        .map(templateDTO -> (TemplateDirectoryDTO) templateDTO)
                                                        .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet()));
        }
        Set<TemplateFile> childFiles = templateDirectory.getChildFiles();
        if (childFiles != null && !childFiles.isEmpty()) {
            templateDirectoryDTO.setTemplates(childFiles
                                                        .stream()
                                                        .map(this::createTemplateDTOFromEntity)
                                                        .map(templateDTO -> (TemplateFileDTO) templateDTO)
                                                        .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet()));
        }

        return templateDirectoryDTO;
    }
}
```

Missing part was

```
Set<TemplateFile> childFiles = templateDirectory.getChildFiles();
        if (childFiles != null && !childFiles.isEmpty()) {
            templateDirectoryDTO.setTemplates(childFiles
                                                        .stream()
                                                        .map(this::createTemplateDTOFromEntity)
                                                        .map(templateDTO -> (TemplateFileDTO) templateDTO)
                                                        .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet()));
        }
```